# I have deleted a StatefulSet on accident and need to re-create it

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

So, dumb me has deleted a very important Statefulset, (I was working in the wrong environment) and need to recover it.
I have the .yaml file and the description (what you get when you get when you click edit on OpenLens).
This stateful set if used for the database and I can not lose the data.
The pvc's and pv's are still there and I have not done anything in fear of losing data.
As you can probably tell, I am not very familiar with Kubernetes and need help restoring my statefulset and not losing data in the process.

As a sidenote, I tried just `kubectl apply -f <file>` in  our dev environment and data gets lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restore the StatefulSet without losing data, you should first check the status of the PersistentVolumeClaims (PVCs) and PersistentVolumes (PVs) associated with the StatefulSet. You can do this by running the kubectl get pvc and kubectl get pv commands. Once you have verified that the PVCs and PVs are intact, you need the same statefulset yaml file for restoring, by using kubectl apply -f command you can recreate the StatefulSet. If you want to ensure that the StatefulSet is restored exactly as it was before it was deleted, you can use the kubectl replace -f  command instead. This will replace the existing StatefulSet with the one defined in the .yaml file, without changing any of the data on the associated PVCs and PVs.

To ensure that your data is not lost in the process, it is recommended that you create a backup of the StatefulSet before performing any of the above commands.

Comment: Yeah in the end I applied the config after setting the PVCs reclaim policy to retain. It is now working.